# Element of order $10$ in $S_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

Let $S_7$ denote the symmetric group of permutations of $7$ symbols. As $|S_7|=7!$ and $10$ divides $7!$, is there an element of order $10$ in this group? If yes, then what is it? Also what would be the largest possible order of any element in $S_7$?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Another hint: what is the prime factorization of $10$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any product of two *disjoint* cycles of order $\;2,\, 5\;$ resp. is an element of order $\;10\;$ , and there are elements of order $\;12\;$ in $\;S_7\;$ , for example $\;(1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6\,7)\;$ .

As any element in $\;S_n\;$ can be expressed as the product of different cycles, and a product of *disjoint* cycles has order the minimal common product of their lengths, now you answer your own last question.

Answer (score 2):

The order of an element in the symmetric group is the lcm of the sizes of its disjoint cycles. So $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$ has order 10. And the order of an element must be less than the largest of $(7/k)^k$ as $k$ varies. Note that $(7/2)^2 = 49/4 > 12$, and in fact there is an element of order 12, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$, and this has the largest possible order as one can see by graphing $\left(\frac{7}{x}\right)^x$ and observing that that it peaks just above 13, but 13 is impossible as an order, since this would require a cycle of size 13.

In general, to find a bound on the order of an element of $S_n$, we can look at the derivative of $\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)^x$,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\exp(x(\ln n -\ln x))=((\ln n -\ln x)+x(-1/x))\exp(x(\ln n-\ln x)),$$
which is 0 when $\ln x= \ln n - 1$, or $x=\frac{n}{e}$. Hence the maximum value of $\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)^x$ is $e^{n/e}$, so this gives a bound on the order of elements of $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

> 10  divides 7!, is there an element of order 10 in this group?

Although in $S_7$ this maybe true (10 divides 7! and the group has an element of order 10), if you look at $S_5$, and 10 divides 5!, there **isn't** any element of order 10.

This is because although the order of the element must divide the order of the group, just because 10 is a divisor of the order of the group that doesn't mean the group must have an element of order 10.

This is only true for *prime* numbers. From Cauchy's Theorem:

> If *p*, a prime, divides the order of the group G, then G has an element of order *p*.

In the case of $S_5$.

> (1) $\#S_5=120=2^3 \times3\times 5 $, so by Cauchy's theorem we know it has elements of order 2, 3 and 5
>
> (2) $S_5$ has all the permutations from 1 to 5

From (2) we know it won't have a single cycle of 10 numbers, so the only other way we can have an element of order 10 is if it's a product of two disjointed cycles of order 2 and 5.

However, since all elements of order 2 are translations $(i k)$ of two numbers from 1 to 5 and all elements of order 5 have to have all the numbers from 1 to 5, the cycles are never disjointed, so there *aren't* any elements of order 10.